# Are Plists not standard practice anymore?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, plist

During the Objective-C days, I used plists extensively to store error and other message strings, so that I don't hard code these in various places in code. When I performed a google search for plists, most of the information I found was dated back to Objective-C (and early Swift) days.

Which made me wonder - is this practice deprecated for some reason? Is it preferred to retain message strings in code files?

Comment: Plists are still supported and nothing has changed. Personally I prefer json with swift because it has flexible structure, is easy to edit or produce with other tools/languages and `Codable` makes it easy to consume in swift.

Comment: why dont you store your strings in a a localizations file

Answer (score 1):

It has not been deprecated and is used very much now a days also. It just depends on the use case and varies person to person.

You are free to use any of the storages - UserDefaults, CoreData, Keychain, Plist, etc which ever suits your requirement.

Happy to help.

Thanks.